# Fail2Ban custom rule fails to use actionban

Tags: fail2ban

I'm trying to develop a custom filter to filter out some malicious attacks/scans on our filters, however I'm stuck at a point that the actionban does not take effect.

This is my jail.local:

```
[my-jail]
enabled = true
filter = my-filter
action = my-action
  sendmail-whois[name=Fail2Ban Test, dest=obfuscated@email.com, sender=EC2-Fail2Ban@emaildomain.com, sendername="Fail2Ban"]
logpath = /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-noname-com-access.log
maxretry = 4
findtime = 60
bantime = 300
journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=httpd.service
```

Now the actions:

```
[Definition]

actionstart = touch /var/log/fail2ban_debug.log
actionstop = rm -f /var/log/fail2ban_debug.log

actionban = /opt/scripts/ban.sh Ban <ip>
actionunban = /opt/scripts/ban.sh Unban <ip>
```

And filter:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> - - \[.*\] \".*.noname.*\" \".*\" [4-5][0-9][0-9]
```

When I run manually to check the filter:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-noname-com-access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/my-filter.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : my-filter, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-noname-com-access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 1474 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1474] ^<HOST> - - \[.*\] \".*.noname.*\" \".*\" [4-5][0-9][0-9]
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [6637] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 6637 lines, 0 ignored, 1474 matched, 5163 missed
[processed in 2.16 sec]
```

I do not get the actionban action anywhere. If I run the command manually I get the desired result, but fail2ban does not initiate that action anywhere.
When I restart the service, I get the e-mails from sendmail. actionstart also creates the file, however actionban and actionunban never happens, although I have 100s of hits per minute.

also logs:

```
2023-10-16 14:04:30,215 fail2ban.server         [4436]: INFO    --------------------------------------------------
2023-10-16 14:04:30,215 fail2ban.server         [4436]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.11.2
2023-10-16 14:04:30,215 fail2ban.server         [4436]: DEBUG   Creating PID file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid
2023-10-16 14:04:30,216 fail2ban.observer       [4436]: INFO    Observer start...
2023-10-16 14:04:30,216 fail2ban.server         [4436]: DEBUG   Starting communication
2023-10-16 14:04:30,218 fail2ban.database       [4436]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,218 fail2ban.jail           [4436]: INFO    Creating new jail 'my-jail'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,224 fail2ban.jail           [4436]: INFO    Jail 'my-jail' uses systemd {}
2023-10-16 14:04:30,224 fail2ban.filter         [4436]: DEBUG   Setting usedns = warn for FilterSystemd(Jail('my-jail'))
2023-10-16 14:04:30,224 fail2ban.filter         [4436]: DEBUG   Created FilterSystemd(Jail('my-jail'))
2023-10-16 14:04:30,224 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [4436]: DEBUG   Created FilterSystemd
2023-10-16 14:04:30,224 fail2ban.jail           [4436]: INFO    Initiated 'systemd' backend
2023-10-16 14:04:30,225 fail2ban.filter         [4436]: DEBUG   Setting usedns = warn for FilterSystemd(Jail('my-jail'))
2023-10-16 14:04:30,225 fail2ban.server         [4436]: DEBUG     failregex: '^<HOST> - - \\[.*\\] \\".*.noname.*\\" \\".*\\" [4-5][0-9][0-9]'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,225 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [4436]: INFO      Added journal match for: '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=httpd.service'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.filter         [4436]: INFO      maxRetry: 4
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.filter         [4436]: INFO      encoding: UTF-8
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.filter         [4436]: INFO      findtime: 60
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.actions        [4436]: INFO      banTime: 300
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4436]: DEBUG   Created <class 'fail2ban.server.action.CommandAction'>
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4436]: DEBUG     Set actionunban = '/opt/scripts/ban.sh Unban <ip>'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4436]: DEBUG     Set actionstop = 'rm -f /var/log/fail2ban_debug.log'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4436]: DEBUG     Set actionban = '/opt/scripts/ban.sh Ban <ip>'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4436]: DEBUG     Set actionstart = 'touch /var/log/fail2ban_debug.log'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4436]: DEBUG     Set actname = 'my-action'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.CommandAction  [4436]: DEBUG     Set name = 'my-action'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,226 fail2ban.jail           [4436]: DEBUG   Starting jail 'my-jail'
2023-10-16 14:04:30,228 fail2ban.jail           [4436]: INFO    Jail 'my-jail' started
2023-10-16 14:04:30,229 fail2ban.transmitter    [4436]: DEBUG   Status: ready
2023-10-16 14:04:30,231 fail2ban.utils          [4436]: DEBUG   7fb62d68f580 -- returned successfully 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I run manually to check the filter ... I do not get the actionban action anywhere.

`fail2ban-regex` does test filter/failregex only. Nothing else.

> `Jail 'my-jail' uses systemd`

this means that fail2ban would monitor systemd journal (probably your default backend), not the log file `/var/log/...-access.log`. If you want monitor `logpath` instead, you need to switch to some file-related backend, like `pyinotify` or `polling` or simply specify `backend = auto` for the jail.

Also note that your regex is a bit vulnerable due to several catch-alls.

And last but not least - note [fail2ban :: wiki :: Best practice (reduce parasitic log-traffic)](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice#reduce-parasitic-log-traffic).